# Is it possible to use Constraints in Navigation bar?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to apply auto-layout constraints in the iOS `UINavigationBar`? How do you implement this?

Comment: Not without a messy subclass.

Comment: Edit feedback: ask your questions directly, without words that don't relate to the question. Also, don't ask 'why': this is often unknowable, and will get your question closed as 'primarily opinion-based'. Note that you should also include in this question what you have tried, and why it's hard to determine if adding these constraints is possible.

Comment: I have up voted urs hope to get it back in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

We dont need the Constraints for UINavigationBar. Try using as shown in image below  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to add constraints programmatically on an instance of `UINavigationBar` because it's inherited from `UIView`. However, it's not that necessary to do so because the position and the shape are set by the best user experience based on **Apple Human Interface Guideline** if you are using `UINavigationController` along with it.

If you want to make your own custom `UINavigationBar`, you better get inherited from `UINavigationBar` and then apply your custom elements.